# Testing a selector for webscraping tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the Web Scraper tool from [webscraper.io](http://webscraper.io).

I'm trying to scrape all of the issues from Marvel and add child selectors to scrape the issues, characters, illustrators, etc.

http://www.comicbookdb.com/publisher.php?ID=4#A

When I click on one of the titles, it instead clicks on the *entire left side of the page* (titles from A-M).

How do I modify the CSS selector in order to only choose specific titles? I tried changing the start URL but it didn't work.

Here is what they have:

```
table:nth-of-type(2) 
td:nth-of-type(1) 
a:nth-of-type(n+2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would iterate through each a inside the parenting table. You would then be able to look at the first letter of the html inside the a element. You can do something with that letter, not sure if you want to only select A-M or if that's what it's doing. If you only want titles with a, you would simple compare the first char to 'a' and if it matches, then select that element, otherwise don't.

Comment: Yeah I can see what you're saying. Thank you, I appreciate it. But I need to put something in the fields next to element preview in order to tell it " No I don't want the entire list, I only want title A-M!!" But I don't know what to put in there.

Comment: It doesn't look like it provides that. I do not believe there would be a sufficient solution for you. What you can do is iterate through each child of that table, and you can say only do y-x (y being the start, x being the end; in your case you'd do 1-13), but that's not exactly stable. Sort of the downside to web scraping, you don't really have access to the information beforehand :P. Good luck though!